# Is it possible for users to search a map to see locations which have been pinned by me in swift

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I am creating an app that has pins which I have added that when clicked open an alert that has information on the building. I want to let users search for these locations but I'm not sure if that's possible because I haven't found any code on it. Please let me know if you know how to do this or have any suggestions.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class CustomPointAnnotiation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var imageName: String!
}

class MapVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var manager = CLLocationManager()

    class Location: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
        var title: String?
        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
        var info: String

        init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, info: String) {
            self.title = title
            self.coordinate = coordinate
            self.info = info
                    }
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        // 1
        let identifier = "Location"

        // 2
        if annotation.isKindOfClass(Location.self) {
            // 3
            var image: UIImageView
            image = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 50,y: 200,width: 250,height: 180))
            image.image = UIImage(named:"")
            self.view.addSubview(image)

            var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)

            if annotationView == nil {
                //4
                annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
                annotationView!.canShowCallout = true

                // 5
                let btn = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
                annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
            } else {
                // 6
                annotationView!.annotation = annotation
            }
            return annotationView
        }

        // 7
        return nil
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        let location = view.annotation as! Location
        let placeName = location.title
        let placeInfo = location.info

        var imageView: UIImageView
        imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 50,y: 200,width: 250,height: 180))
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        if location.title == "Woodburn Hall" {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named:"woodburn.png")
            self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        }
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: placeName, message:placeInfo, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))

       self.presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)

       imageView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self

        // Core Location
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        //set initial location to Indiana University
        let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 39.17, longitude: -86.5148)
        let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 100

        func centerMapOnLocation(location:CLLocation){
            let coordinateRegion =
            MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
            mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)


            mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid;
        }

        centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)

        let unionLocation = Location(title: "Memorial Union", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 39.167541, longitude: -86.522387), info: "Address: 900 E 7th St, Bloomington, IN 47408 \n The student union on the campus. Was dedicated in June of 1932. As of date, it is the second largest student union, worldwide. Has multiple stages, offices, directors offices, and even a hotel in the building.")

        mapView.addAnnotation(unionLocation)

        let ashtonLocation = Location(title: "Ashton Residence Hall", coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 39.171550, longitude: -86.509768), info: "Address: 1800 E 10th St, Bloomington, IN 47408 \n Includes single dorms only and is located in central neighborhood.")

        mapView.addAnnotation(ashtonLocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help much if you may tell us how or where you are saving those pins. Do you have a backend that you add your pins dynamically or are they "hardcoded" in your application? First, you need some saving mechanism that the other parts of your code can reach that data.

If you are saving them dynamically to a database by using an API, the best way would be to develop a method that takes your search parameters and return the results.

If the pins are saved to a database or file that is shipped with your application, then you need appropriate methods to query those pins from whatever file, format or database.